Subrayado amarillo en comentarios en vscode ¿Por qué me aparece?
Estoy trabajando en vscode, programando en Python y me subraya los comentarios con amarillo cuando hago comentarios de varias líneas, usando '''Este'''. ¿Alguien me podría indicar como resolverlo de alguna manera? muchas gracias.

Probaste a mantener el ratón encima de las líneas?? Te dice exactamente cual es el problema... porque nosotros aquí adivinos, no somos

Horacio, un subrayado amarillo, es una alerta/warning. Significa que hay un detalle en ese sector. Si puedes toma una imagen de dicho warning, y compartela en la publicación.

Como te comenta Benito, el linter te debería mostrar claramente la causa del warning si posicionas el puntero encima. No se si es la razón porque dependerá del linter y si se preocupa por estas convenciones de estilo, pero en Python los comentarios usan siempre #, tanto los de bloque como los de una sola linea. Las comillas triples denotan literales de cadena siempre, excepto cuando conforman cadenas de documentación: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar triple comillas dobles (""") y almohadilla (#) para comentar en Python?
